Lower bound on the order of balanced separator?
A balanced separation of an $n$-vertex graph $G$ is a pair $(A,B)$ of subsets of $V(G)$ such that $A\cup B=V(G)$ and there is no edge between $A\setminus B$ and $B\setminus A$, and $|A\setminus B|\le 2n/3$ and $|B\setminus A|\le 2n/3$.
Define $s(G)=\min_{\text{$(A,B)$ is a balanced separation of $G$}} |A\cap B|$.
I am wondering is there any parameter related to (the lower bound on) $s(G)$?
In this paper, they study the relation between so called separation number and treewidth, which I feel is more close to the maximum size of the separator, not the minimum one.
